# TwoPanes and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a screen that is trying to use `fragments` to create two panes in the event that an app is turned sideways.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="edu.temple.lordprettystocko.LordPrettyStocko">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/portfolio_frag"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/stockdetails_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout file. Below is my related code.

```
 twoPanes = (findViewById(R.id.stockdetails_frag)!= null);
```

This line is giving me the error that it cant find the variable `stockdetails_frag` even though it is clearly declared.

Layout File for portrait

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.temple.lordprettystocko.LordPrettyStocko">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/portfolio_frag"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So I should add it here?

Any hints?

Comment: clean your project and build again.

Comment: share error logcat...

Comment: wait why isnt that the point of creating a landscape version in the design part

Comment: http://android-kaizen.com/2015/01/04/tutorial-multi-pane-fragments/

Comment: @MikeM. please see my edits

Comment: OK, now I'm not sure what you were asking. Are you saying that you couldn't find `stockdetails_frag` even while in landscape orientation?

Comment: No I couldnt find while compiling lol

Comment: Oh. My bad. Clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: I have another issue I wish I could get like personel help from you

Comment: That's not really how SO works. Is it just a quick question related to this?

Comment: Um yes and no
I have a listview that is not populating with data when I attempt to add to it through an activity. I did not want to copy and paste the entire thing here so that's why I didnt do it

Comment: Yeah, that's a separate question. Sorry. I'll be around for a coupla more hours, though, so I'll take a look if I see it posted.

Comment: got skype by any chance?